# How can an army be justified with the right to physical and psychological integrity?

Tags: ethics, society

The human being has a right to physical and psychological integrity. If a person dies during a military operation, the relatives receive compensation from the state. However, financial compensation is not protection against physical damage. How can a society wage war when it knows that this deprives people of their right to integrity? 
How can an army be justified that only men are obliged to serve if they also have a right to unharmed lives?

Comment: If this question comes from reading a certain text referencing that text would help provide context and help keep any answers from being primarily opinion-based. Welcome!

Comment: The short answer is that war is 'legal in almost all states. Further, most modern states have volunteer soldiers who implicitely waive any pertinent human rights. But you have put your finger on one of the anachronisms of modern states.

Comment: A small nit: If drone /robot technology advances enough we will be able to "kill blissfully" without an army. Will your question go away?

Comment: Alas, nature does not recognize people's right to "physical and psychological integrity". The elements harm and kill people all the time, so do other people, individually and in groups, small and large. If this right is to have any content it has to be protected, having an army (and also police, firefighters, etc.) is part of this protection system. There are arguments to be made about possible injustices, including pre-emptive wars and the gender gap, but they have to be be based on something more salient than "right to unharmed lives", see e.g. [just war](https://www.iep.utm.edu/justwar/).

Comment: The question has no text as background. The question refers more to states with an official duty, especially where the official duty only concerns the man. If robots wage war, the question would be so far obsolete that a society only goes as far as the national border.